# Let's talk about tag wikis

Tags: discussion, tags

According to SEDE, we have 104 unique tags for our 244 questions. Almost one out of five of the questions is tagged with [user-behavior](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-behavior) and almost one out of seven is tagged with [problem-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-users). Only one of those two has a wiki entry.

This is the same statistic for the [first page](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/tags?page=1&tab=popular) of tags (sorted by popularity): over half of the tags don't have wiki entries. It gets worse on the subsequent pages of tags.

Let's improve the tag guidance for at least our top tags. The tags listed below are from our most popular tags and don't contain any guidance.

- [user-behavior](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-behavior) - This is our most popular tag, with 46 questions. Many of the questions with this tag boil down to "How do I handle a user that does X?" Is this the correct tag for this type of question, or should these questions have more specific tags?
- [rules-and-policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-and-policies) - This tag has 18 existing questions. It was [created](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/) out of a merge between [rules](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules) and [policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/policies). The type of questions in this tag seem varied from how to handle individual user issues to how to improve user engagement to general policy guidance.
- [site-growth](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-growth) - This tag has 14 existing questions. The questions in this tag seem to mostly reflect a "How do I grow my user base". I think this tag just needs a little wiki love, most of the questions appear to fit. There are a [couple](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/835/) of [questions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/965/) that may not fit with this tag though.
- [web-forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-forums) - This tag has 13 questions. It's closely related [forum-software](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum-software) has an additional 4. I'm not sure how to handle these. [forum-software](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum-software) seems to have more technical questions. 3 out of the 4 are also tagged with [web-forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-forums). The [web-forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-forums) has a variety of questions, many tangentially touching on forum utilization, but [often](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/972/) [trying](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/929/) to [solve](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/873/) a [general](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/858/) [community](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/738/) [problem](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/732/). I think these two tags need some clarification and once that's done, some of the questions with these tags may lose one or both of them.
- [disciplinary-actions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplinary-actions) - This tag has 12 questions. It seems pretty well defined in terms of the questions associated with the tag. I think we just need some wiki love here too.
- [participation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participation) - This tag has 11 questions. The questions in this tag seem to be a variation of "How do I increase user participation". I think we need some wiki love here too. [This](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37) question may not belong in the tag though. I don't think it's a "participation" question.
- [moderator-relationship](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-relationship) - This tag has 7 questions. The questions in this tag do not seem to revolve around a consistent theme. Some of the questions are about finding moderators. Some are about how a moderator should interact with users. Others are about how moderators should deal with inaccuracies within the community. This tag needs clarification and some of the questions need to be categorized. There is also a [suggestion](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/131/) to kill the tag completely. I am not opposed to this action.
- [site-administration](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-administration) - This tag also has 7 questions. A majority of the questions deal with how to interact with the highest power in a community. However, [some](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/379/) of the [questions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/638/) do not fall into this general categorization.

---

I've listed our 8 most popular tags without wiki guidance on how to utilize them. What are your opinions on how they are utilized? For the ones that don't appear to be utilized consistently, how can we categorize those questions to fit better?

I'd also be interested in hearing what tags you think should exist but don't. Perhaps those non-existent tags could help categorize our questions more effectively.

Comment: Re [tag:moderator-relationship]: I still think [we should kill it](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/171/83).

Comment: I'd forgotten about that discussion. I'd edited my post to include a link to that discussion. I'm not opposed to killing it either. There doesn't seem to be consistency when using it, making it hard to pin down how to use it properly.

Comment: Related (on tag philosophy): http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1255/83

Answer (score 6):

## Duplicate Tags: ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), except [real-life](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) vs. [physical-communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-communities))

There are a lot of tags that should be combined.

**Proposal (to vote on):**

- [money](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/money) ----> [finance](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finance) **Done**
- [start-up](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/start-up) ----> [new-communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-communities) **Done**
- [edit-war](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edit-war) ----> [editing](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editing) **Done**
- [real-life](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-life) ----> [physical-communities](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physical-communities)
- [trolls](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trolls) ----> [problem-users](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-users) **Done**
- [karma](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karma), [reputation](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reputation) ----> [gamification](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gamification) **Done**
- [bans](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bans), [hellban](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hellban) ----> [disciplinary-actions](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disciplinary-actions) **Done**

In addition, there are a lot of tags about moderator methodologies. These all cover one basic topic: how to moderate your moderators. Suggestion: merge all of these into [moderators](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators):

- [moderator-selection](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-selection) **Done**
- [moderator-teams](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-teams) **Done**

  - Also, [moderation-team](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderation-team) **Done**
- [moderator-relationship](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-relationship) **Done**
- [moderator-access](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-access) **Done**
- [team-duration](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/team-duration) **Done**
- [powers](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers) **Done**
- [training](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/training) **Done**
- [moderator-elections](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-elections) **Done**
- [moderator-responsibility](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderator-responsibility) **Done**

Comment: Merging these, in combination with Monica's [answer](http://meta.communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/a/1250/78) may take care of some of the "bad users" tags

Comment: I'm not sure on start-up vs small communities.  There is a difference between a currently small group that is designed to be larger and high growth vs a small community that is designed to start and stay small.

Comment: I'm not sure about real-life vs physical-communities.  There is a difference between issues that occur as a result of real life issues or conflicts vs necessarily being a physical community.

Comment: @AJHenderson RE: start-up vs. small communities: I mostly agree, although I feel like start-up should be something more like new-communities.

Comment: @AJHenderson RE: real-life vs. physical-communities: they seem like they would be used interchangeably, and we can't rely on tag wikis for people to always know the difference. Plus, what is the advantage of that one tag? I can only see a handful of events that would need that tag.

Comment: I agree with some of these but not others, making voting hard. What's the best way to provide that kind of feedback?

Comment: I agree with merging reputation and karma into gamification, but I'm not sure about voting.  Voting is gamification but it's *also* public ratings -- that is, votes (more than any other game elements) help the *readers* more than the *posters*.  So we might want to keep that separate, at least for now.

Comment: On the user-behavior cluster, I think conflict-resolution is a separate thing.  Note that bullying can be done by users *and* mods, and I'm pretty sure we've got a couple of questions about the latter, though perhaps a moderator-behavior tag (parallel with user-behavior) would be better.  On the other hand, vague.  Hmm.

Comment: If you're proposing merging bans and hellbans into disciplinary-actions, I agree.

Comment: The last cluster could all be collapsed into a single "moderators" tag, now that that's not the name of our site.  Choosing them, training them, handling issues with them, how they work together... all one bucket with our current site scope.

Comment: @Monica I thought of splitting them up into a ton of answers to vote on, but that probably would have cluttered the page too much. I can still do that, though. (also: Please note it is a community wiki for a reason)

Answer (score 5):

Most of our tags date from the time we were Moderators, not Community Building, and I often feel like I can't quite find the right tags for a question -- but if I knew what tags we needed I'd just make them.  We should create (or improve) wikis for the tags we use, but I wonder if we should look at our tag ontology from a higher level first.  For example, moderators refer to "users" but I'm not sure plain old community members do; maybe we should be thinking about "members", "participants", "curators", "moderators"...?  And maybe instead of "rules-and-policies" (merger acknowledged there) and "problem-users" we should be thinking about specific areas, like "intellectual-property" (plagiarism, copyright) and "bullying" (we have that) and other things that communities make rules/policies about.

I don't have specific proposals and I'm not sure how we should *discuss* this, but it feels like we should, somehow.

Comment: I think you are right. Most, if not all, of our tags reflect the moderators viewpoint and were created before the change. I really like the idea of more common "community building" tags. The idea of more specific tags related to policies is a good one too. I think it is much more likely that someone is going to Google "how to deal with plagiarism in a community" than "community rules and policies". It is a much more specific and concrete problem they want ideas on.

Comment: For your last sentence: I don't think that we can simply clean up the tags in one round. I'm hoping (with my answers I posted) that we can start weeding out some of the obvious duplicates and meta-tags so we have a smaller list of tags to refine.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin right, tag-cleanup is an iterative process.  We won't do it all at once.

Answer (score 4):

## "Hopeless Tags:" ([status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed))

Some tags that *I* think are highly localized:

- [ignore-list](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ignore-list) - The only question tagged with this has no other tags. What is an appropriate replacement? **DONE**
- [guest-content](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guest-content) **DONE**
- [abuse](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abuse): not quite sure about this one but it's kinda vague and it could be replaced with something a lot more specific  **DONE**
- [owner](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/owner): I don't see any purpose of this tag that would make it easier to find a question... **DONE**

Comment: The one question that is currently tagged "abuse" could be instead tagged "conflict-resolution".

Comment: Each of these tags currently has one question, so retagging won't have widespread impact.  Let's do it.

Comment: It looks like `ignore-list` is the only one remaining. Suggestions on an alternative? The question it's associated with only has the one tag.

Comment: @Andy per-user-customizations?  Site-design (it's a UX question, in a way)?

Comment: @Andy perhaps we need a UX tag? It seems like grouping those into one tag wouldn't be that evil...

Answer (score -4):

## Platform Specific Tags: ([status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined))

Idea: **nuke all the platform-specific tags**. We don't allow technology questions, so I don't see why we need tags like [reddit](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reddit) or [stack-exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange). Instead, we should have questions on the *context* (i.e. [forum](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forum) or [wiki](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiki)).

They aren't useful, since the actual software shouldn't matter unless dealing with how to use a piece of software. In that case, it's off topic anyway, so it should be closed.

**So, proposal (to vote on):**

- Rename [web-forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-forums) to [forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forums)

  - Also, nuke all of these tags and replace them with [forums](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forums)

    - Nuke [stack-exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) (the tag only!)...
    - Nuke [reddit](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reddit)
- Also, merge [wikisource](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wikisource) into [wiki](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wiki)
- In addition, nuke [facebook](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook)

  - Create a [social-media](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) tag and rename it.

I'm pretty sure I can set up the mod tools so, whenever someone tries to tag it with [facebook](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), it will automatically replace it with the [social-media](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/social-media) tag.

Comment: The only bullet I'm not entirely sure I agree with is the renaming everything to forums. Are we sure that platform isn't important? Alternatively, do we have some questions tagged `reddit` that are off topic?

Comment: [Example One](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/931/) - The comments acknowledge both dual narrow/broad scope of this question. It is how limitations of migrating from a forum to reddit

Comment: [Example Two](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/999/) - This one is about encouraging users to report properly, in the context, of reddit. The answer provided is fairly generic, but does offer a couple reddit specific guidelines.

Comment: [Example Three](http://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/123/) - This one asks how to protect against blog spam on reddit. The answer provided (full disclosure: It's mine) provides a technical option. There is probably a more generic answer available, but since the question was asked in the context of reddit, that is what I provided.

Comment: @Andy I'm not entirely sure what I *do* think of making these tags more broad (I added this question to prompt discussion). I feel like we're putting too much emphasis on the platform, not the site. A solution that would work Wikipedia should work on a Github wiki with the same exact problem, so why choose to single out single platforms and create unnecessary emphasis on the platform? At the same time, we do need to work within the confines of the tools of a platform, so that *could* be helpful to include the tag...

Comment: "They aren't useful, since the actual software shouldn't matter unless dealing with how to use a piece of software." I disagree with this assertion. It would be reasonable if all communities shared the same culture, and had a universal set of standards.  As it is, this is not the case, and I wouldn't be able to continue asking questions here because platform-agnostic answers aren't of much value to me.  Maybe that is the direction that you guys want to take the site, but I think starting from a place where all questions/answers should be platform-agnostic is a flawed premise.

Comment: Even using the example of the Wikipedia and GitHub wiki, is it really correct that problems should be solved the same in both communities? Does the userbase of these communities share standards for conflict resolution, wiki management, etc.?  Certainly the tools and infrastructure could be similar, but the communities that exist on these sites could contextually be very different. An action on the GitHub wiki may not also be appropriate on Wikipedia, and vise-versa.

Comment: @HyperAnthony no, that is not what I meant. Tags are to make questions easy to find and, by creating a tag for each platform, we require people to look through handfuls of tags instead of one. You can say people can add both the broad and the specific tag, but in practice, that never works. Platform is important, but I don't think it is in the context of tags, personally.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin I agree with Hyper Anthony.  The differences among Stack Exchange, Reddit, and game servers are not *just* technical matters of platform; they involve different cultural norms and an answer that's appropriate for SE might be exactly wrong for a game server or a Facebook group.  If the question is actually general then it should also get a general tag like web-forum or voting or trolls or whatever the question is about, but there's no reason to omit the platform in cases where it's actually relevant.

Comment: @MonicaCellio OK, but there is only a correlation between platform/community when the site uses in-house software. Having a PHPBB tag lets me know nothing about the community, and I don't see it worthwhile to grant "my-awesome-forum" tags. I'm not opposed to having specific tags, but I don't see how to regulate it. I must be missing something here :)

Comment: And clarification: I'm saying platform isn't important... *in the tags only*. Yes, the wiki was a bad example (my apologies for the confusion).

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin I that only *certain* platforms rate tags.  If PHPBB is an implementation only (I don't know it so can't say), then that'd be like having a tag for some specific web server or something -- I agree that's not helpful.  But communities on Stack Exchange, Reddit, and Facebook (as examples) all have to fit into a given framework and *tend* to have certain cultural expectations in common, so tags for those make sense to me.  We'll *also* have generic ones like "discussion-forum" and "email" ("email-list"?) and "game-server" (that might not be the right name). Does that make sense?

Comment: @MonicaCellio but what makes Stack Exchange so special that it gets its own tag? That's what I'm trying to address... there isn't a "firefox-development" tag on Stack Overflow, nor is there a "google" tag on The Workplace. *That's* what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin Stack Exchange has 135 communities that all operate on a common platform, with common actions available to users, and with common expectations of users.  A question about gamification *on your own site*, where you can change the badges, milestones, etc, will be different from one about gamification on an SE site, so that's an important piece of information.  Maybe it only belongs in the question body and not the tags, but my gut feeling is that SE, Reddit, and Facebook are all big enough, and different enough from "average", to rate tags.